# XSLT using a sibling node to generate xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml

```
<FRA>
   <Id>USD Libor Futures</Id>
   <PriceBasis>EuroDollar</PriceBasis>
</FRA>
```

I would like the following output

```
    <FRA>
      <Id>USD Libor Futures</Id>
      <PriceBasis>EuroDollar</PriceBasis>
      <ModifyMktData srcontractid="USD Libor Futures Convexity" optype="add" srctype="Spread" dsttype="Price"/>
   </FRA>
```

I am using the following xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>  

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">  
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="FRA/PriceBasis">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:variable name="fraid" select="Id"/>
    <ModifyMktData>
      <Update srccontractid="{$fraid} Convexity" optype="add" srctype="Spread" dsttype="Price"/>
    </ModifyMktData>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output from the xslt looks like this:

```
<FRA>
  <Id>USD LIBOR Futures</Id>
  <PriceBasis>EuroDollar</PriceBasis>
  <ModifyMktData>
     <Update srccontractid=" Convexity" optype="add" srctype="Spread" dsttype="Price" />
   </ModifyMktData
</FRA>
```

I am essentially looking to reuse the Id in the attribute for ModifyMktData. Obviously the xslt I have does not work as I would like it to. It does not add the Id field to the srccontractid field.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is *context*. At the point where you define a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="fraid" select="Id"/>
```

You are inside a template that matches `PriceBasis` elements. This means that the context of this variable definition is a particular `PriceBasis` element. But, apparently, a `PriceBasis` element does not have a child element `Id`.

Instead, `Id` is a child element of `FRA`. In this context, the right path to `Id` is:

```
../Id
```

The stylesheet below simplifies the code, it does not use a variable at all. For an expression as short as `../Id` I don't see why you would need a variable. You can place a path expression directly inside the attribute value template brackets:

```
{../Id}
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>  

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">  
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PriceBasis">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <ModifyMktData>
      <Update srccontractid="{../Id} Convexity" optype="add" srctype="Spread" dsttype="Price"/>
    </ModifyMktData>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Input**

Your input is not well-formed and will not be accepted by any XML application. Assuming the following input, where the `Fra` element is closed again:

```
<FRA>
   <Id>USD Libor Futures</Id>
   <PriceBasis>EuroDollar</PriceBasis>
</FRA>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FRA>
   <Id>USD Libor Futures</Id>
   <PriceBasis>EuroDollar</PriceBasis>
   <ModifyMktData>
      <Update srccontractid="USD Libor Futures Convexity" optype="add" srctype="Spread" dsttype="Price"/>
   </ModifyMktData>
</FRA>
```

Comment: Thanks that did it. I did not want to post my entire massive xml and just hand typed it hence the errors. Your solution worked. I did not realize the context was necessary.

Comment: @rk540 You are welcome. Please consider accepting the answer you found was the most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First, your template is matching `FRA/PriceBasis`, which doesn't exist in the input.  It looks like you want to match just `FRA` instead.

Second, you're creating an `Update` node under your `ModifyMktData` node, which is not in your desired output as listed above.

Aside from that, what you're doing looks like it should work.

Comment: Looks like an error in my copy paste of xml. Correcting it. Thanks. The xslt for some reason does not work I am not sure why. The out put I end up with is as follows:

Comment: It looks like you still haven't copied everything correctly.  If your template is matching on `FRA/PriceBasis`, it should be creating the `ModifyMktData` node inside `PriceBasis`, which is not what you show in your output.  I think if you match on `FRA` instead of `FRA/PriceBasis`, you will get your desired output.